# Storm: Nginx or Maven or Zookeeper

Tags: maven, nginx, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am new to using Twitter Storm for data streaming but I've being having some issues when running the examples. As there are examples using Zookeeper, there are also using Maven and another one using Nginx. Also two at the time combined. 
Could anyone please make my mind clear of when I should use any of them or two of them at the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat hard to answer your question because Zookeeper, Maven, and Nginx all do very different things, but I'll try my best.

Zookeeper is part of running Storm. It keeps track of the current transactions running through your Storm topologies.

Maven is a tool for build management that is common in the JVM ecosystem. You'll need this to build stuff.

Nginx might be used in some cases with Storm topologies, but it is certainly not required or common to all use cases.

So you might need all three in your project, you will certainly need Zookeeper and almost certainly interact with Maven in some way, even if you are using Ant or Leinengen elsewhere. Nginx is more project specific, and even if you need an HTTP server, you don't have to use Nginx.